# How can I make the selected file type acceptable only as docx, using FilePond?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, filepond

How can I make the selected file type acceptable only as `docx`?
I want the selected file to have a `docx` extension only. What kind of filtering should I apply? How can I do that?

**React code sample**

```
return (
    <>
        <Form className='orange-color ml-2'>
            <FilePond
                ref={ref => (ref)}
                allowFileEncode={true}
                allowMultiple={false}
                oninit={() =>
                    console.log("FilePond "+formKey.toString()+" has initialised")
                }

                onupdatefiles={(fileItems) => {
                    const file = fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)

                    if (file[0]) {
                        const reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);

                        reader.onload = (event) => {
                            const convertedResult = event.target.result

                            if (convertedResult) {
                                const regex = '(.*)(base64,)(.*)';
                                const matches = convertedResult.match(regex);
                                const val = matches[3];

                                changeSelected(val)
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }

                }
            />
            <Form.Check>
                <Form.Check.Input required
                                  checked={input.value !== null}
                                  style={{display:'none' }}
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid" >Required</Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Check>
        </Form>
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The File Type Validation plugin handles blocking of files that are of the wrong type. When creating a FilePond instance based on a input type file, this plugin will automatically interpret the accept attribute value.

https://github.com/pqina/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type

Comment: i didn't understand how to add the file extension i want

Comment: I haven't used FilePond before but from the docs it looks like it just reads the standard input accept attribute. So it should just need to be ```acceptedFileTypes: ['.docx'],``` See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/#custom-type-detection

Comment: @MystikDeveloped validation by extension is currently not supported. See https://github.com/pqina/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type/issues/4 for how to validate based on mimetype.

Answer (score 0):

Filepond has a plugin for file types: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-validate-type/

Comment: Is it used as 'acceptedFileTypes = {' docx '}'? I couldn't see an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
acceptedFileTypes={'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}
```

**Code example**

```
<Form className='orange-color ml-2'>
                    <FilePond
                        ref={ref => (ref)}
                        allowFileEncode={true}
                        allowMultiple={false}
                        acceptedFileTypes={'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}

......
```